# change html5 video controls layout when fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm following [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos) tutorial on how to change html5 video controls layout. But when i go fullscreen mode, the controls goes back to default. Do anyone have an example on how i can change the layout in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the native controls completely, in both normal and full-screen mode:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
  display:none !important;
}
```

Set the `z-index` for the custom controls to be equal to or higher than `2147483647`:

```
#video-controls {
  z-index: 2147483647;
}
```

Source: [Hiding Native HTML5 Video Controls in Full-Screen Mode](http://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/)

Note: if you are following the [tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos), then you need to also set `position` of custom controls to make it visible:

```
#video-controls {
  z-index: 2147483647;
  position: absolute; /* top left corner, change it if you like */
}
```