# CSS how to disable microsoft edge media controls in fullscreen mode?

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following code which switches my video into fullscreen mode using my custom controls:

```
 fullScreenButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
              if (video.requestFullscreen) {
                video.videoContainer.requestFullscreen();
              } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                video.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
              } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                video.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
              }
 });
```

This works great but when I switch to fullscreen the custom controls are not there and the default edge controls are. For chrome I did this:

```
::-webkit-media-controls {
  display:none !important;
}
```

And that worked but I dont know how to do it for Microsoft Edge or FireFox. Can someone please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

From this question:[change html5 video controls layout when fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318367/change-html5-video-controls-layout-when-fullscreen)

it seems like what you need to do is reference the entire controls enclosure to hide it:

```
::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
 display:none !important;
}
```

and you need to set your z-index above 2147483647

and set your custom controls to `position: absolute;`

Again, not my work or code, just did some research and it seems like what you're looking for.