# To show a division on Fullscreen mode of YouTube video in IFrame

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I am using YouTube iFrame API to load the YouTube video.
I want to load a customize control bar on the video in fullsrceen mode.Can some body help me.

My code is:-For iFrame

```
 <div class="row" style="position: fixed; display: block " id="youtubeDiv">
          <iframe id="youtube_videos_url" allowfullscreen="1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
                  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8xXrbKJSp6w?wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1&version=3&autoplay=0&controls=0" frameborder="0">
          </iframe>
          <div id="video_controls" class="controls" style="display: block">//some code</div>
        </div>
```

The Button for Fullscreen is

```
 <button id="fs" type="button" data-state="go-fullscreen">Fullscreen</button>
```

The Jquery for the fullscreen is

```
$('#fs').on('click', function () {
        var $$ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
        var iframe = $$('#youtube_videos_url');
        var req = iframe.requestFullscreen
            || iframe.webkitRequestFullscreen
            || iframe.mozRequestFullScreen
            || iframe.msRequestFullscreen;
        req.call(iframe);
});
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change html5 video controls layout when fullscreen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318367/change-html5-video-controls-layout-when-fullscreen)