# Custom HTML5 Video Controls doesn't appear in fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

so I've built a custom html controls for the `<video>` element and hooked it up to JavaScript to make the video functionality work, it all working just fine.

The issue is when I call `requestFullscreen()`, The default browser controls show on fullscreen preview, the easy fix was to remove it from css like so:

**Css**

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display: none !important;
}
```

And now the video is in fullscreen without the controls, now I can't control the video and the HTML controls aren't being shown in fullscreen, I tried fixing it by adding `z-index:100` but that didn't work.

I saw this post from 8 years ago:
[change html5 video controls layout when fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318367/change-html5-video-controls-layout-when-fullscreen)

But this answer also didn't work for me, and I think there should be a better way to do it right?

It doesn't even work in css-tricks tutorial demo here:
[custom controls in html5 video full screen](https://%20https://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/#aa-demo)

My Question is:

How can I allow the HTML5 controls element (found in HTML) to show in fullscreen mode.

**HTML**

```
<div class="vd-wrapper">

 <div class="video">
                <video width="640" height="360">
<source src="./assests/video-sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

```
30| <div class="controls">
31| // Controls HTML5... 
201| <svg id="full-screen-icon">
230| </div>
231| </div> <!-- vid-wrapper -->
```

**JS**

```
let fullScreen = document.getElementById("full-screen-icon");
fullScreen.addEventListener("click", toggleFullScreen);


function toggleFullScreen() {
    video.requestFullscreen().catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

##### Control Bar:

[image]

#### Video On Fullscreen (before)

[image]

#### Video On Fullscreen (after)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you request fullscreen, you need to use the wrapper `div` not the `video` control for the element - e.g. `div.requestFullscreen()`. There is no need for the `z-index` hack either.

The code below won't run in the snippet because SO blocks fullscreen mode and also won't load videos.
If you cut and paste the code with a valid video source, this will work.

Note, since it's the wrapper div which is going full screen, it is up to you to make sure that your video element (and custom controls) resize to fill your video div wrapper.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  let fullScreen = document.getElementById("full-screen-icon");
  fullScreen.addEventListener("click", toggleFullScreen);

  let playButton = document.getElementById("play");
  playButton.addEventListener("click", play);
}

function toggleFullScreen() {
  var div = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  div.requestFullscreen().catch(e => console.log(e));
}

function play(){
  let video = document.getElementById("video");
  video.load();
  video.play();  
}
```

```html
  <div id="wrapper" class="vd-wrapper">

    <div class="video-wrapper">
      <video id="video" width="640" height="360">      
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">
      <button id="full-screen-icon">Fullscreen</button>
      <button id="play">play</button>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- vid-wrapper -->
```